# Adding clip function to python buffer script

Tags: arcpy, buffer, dissolve, erase

I have posted my script for buffering and dissolving polygons.

Could someone help me incorporate an Erase function in order to erase the input file from the buffer?

Script:

```
import arcpy

infc = r'C:\My\File\Input.shp.shp'
outfc = r'C:\My\File\Output.shp'
bufferDistance = 76.2

arcpy.Buffer_analysis(infc, outfc, bufferDistance, "", "", "ALL")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Advanced License of ArcGIS you could use the Erase function after buffering the `infc`:

```
arcpy.Erase_analysis(infc, outfc, r'C:\My\File\EraseOutput.shp','#')
```

Comment: In case anyone does not have an Advanced license, you can accomplish the same thing by doing a union and keeping only desired features.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Is there a way that this function could be incorporated into the script so that only one polygon is being processed? I understand that I could erase the output file once it is buffered, but I was hoping there was a way to make it more streamlined.